# Enter a password using BOTH enter key and "Submit" button (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm relatively new to making websites, however, I am trying to use HTML/Javascript so the user can enter a password using either the ENTER key or the "Submit" button, whichever the user chooses. My code works when I simply print a message like "Welcome!" but when I want to redirect them to another page like "intro.html," thats when it stops working. I have attached my code. I understand event.keyCode may not be javascript and may be jquery? If so, please let me know how to implement jquery into html or any other ideas you all may have :) Thank you so much!

Log In

```
<script language = "JavaScript">
    function showPass(form){

        var pass = form.pwd.value;
        var pass1 = "tanwebdesign"
        var pass2 = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if(pass == pass1 || ((pass == pass1) && pass2 == 13))
        {
            window.location.replace("intro.html");
        }
        else{
            window.open = "LogIn.html"
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<form>

    Password: <input type = "password" name = "pwd" /> 

        <input type = "submit" style = "display: none"  onclick = "showPass(form)" />

        <input type = "button" value = "Log In" onclick = "showPass(form)" />
</form>
```

Comment: add `form.preventDefault();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how it can be done

- No need to add two `input`s makes the same action
- Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent form's default redirect .. see `function showPass(form , e)` and in html `onSubmit = "showPass(this , event)"` you can use `onSubmit` for a form instead of `onClick` for a submit input
- No need to catch the `ENTER` keypress it will work automatically with a form
- To redirect the page you can use `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'`

```js
function showPass(form , e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pass = form.pwd.value;
    var pass1 = "tanwebdesign";
    alert(pass);
    if(pass == pass1 || pass == pass1)
    {
        //window.location.replace("intro.html");
    }
    else{
        //window.open = "LogIn.html"
    }
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit = "showPass(this , event)">
    Password:
    <input type = "password" name = "pwd" /> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "Log In" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful :) Thank you so much again and have a great day!

Comment: you're totally welcome @webdesignweeb .. Have a great day too :-)